# Version of Farkas Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

In lecture we had this version of Farkas lemma:

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$. The system $Ax\leq b$ has no solution $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists y\in \mathbb{R}^m_+$ so that
$$A^ty=0 \quad \text{and} \quad b^ty >0$$

I tried understanding that with an example and came up with $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1&-1 \\ -1&1\end{pmatrix}$, $b=  \begin{pmatrix} -1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. That system obviously has no solution for $x$ but it seems like I can't find a fitting $y$ so that both two conditions are true.

What am I missing? Or is the lecture version of Farkas lemma incorrect?

Comment: Should that be $A^ty = 0$ and $b^t y \color{red}< 0$ instead? [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma#Variants) indicates that that is the case.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes! It's probably a typo then.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2352396/173147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is noted in the comments, it seems that the culprit is a typo. The correct version of Farkas' lemma is that $Ax \leq 0$ fails to have a solution iff there exists a $y \in \Bbb R_{+}^m$ such that $A^ty = 0$ and $b^ty \color{red} < 0$.